Fedora 39 - Is it hardware or software problems?
Quite often my system freezes. I've experienced two instances of this "freezing":

The first type is when all of a sudden the whole display freezes, the keyboard and mouse are still lit up and seem to be working but I don't see any change on the screen. So I have to restart the system. Can't figure out what triggers this.

The second type of freeze happens when I press the "windows key" which shows all the open pages. The display freezes, the mouse still moves, but I can't input anything. I can only control the mouse movement.


On top of that the system sometimes suddenly decides to reboot. I'm at my wits end honestly.
I've got a brand new pc, no past OSs on it, I've got Fedora 39 from the start.
I'm a first time linux user. Please point me in the direction of where to look for. What logs do I need to look at to figure out if it's an hardware or software problem?
root@fedora:~# lshw -short
H/W path         Device          Class          Description
===========================================================
                                 system         System Product Name (SKU)
/0                               bus            PRIME Z790-A WIFI
/0/0                             memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/c                             memory         64GiB System Memory
/0/c/0                           memory         16GiB DIMM Synchronous 6000 MHz (0.2 ns)
/0/c/1                           memory         16GiB DIMM Synchronous 6000 MHz (0.2 ns)
/0/c/2                           memory         16GiB DIMM Synchronous 6000 MHz (0.2 ns)
/0/c/3                           memory         16GiB DIMM Synchronous 6000 MHz (0.2 ns)
/0/1d                            memory         384KiB L1 cache
/0/1e                            memory         256KiB L1 cache
/0/1f                            memory         16MiB L2 cache
/0/20                            memory         33MiB L3 cache
/0/21                            memory         384KiB L1 cache
/0/22                            memory         768KiB L1 cache
/0/23                            memory         12MiB L2 cache
/0/24                            memory         33MiB L3 cache
/0/25                            processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-14700K
/0/100                           bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1                         bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1/0                       display        AD107 [GeForce RTX 4060]
/0/100/1/0.1     card1           multimedia     NVIDIA Corporation
/0/100/1/0.1/0   input14         input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/0/100/1/0.1/1   input15         input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/0/100/1/0.1/2   input16         input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8
/0/100/1/0.1/3   input17         input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9
/0/100/6                         bridge         Raptor Lake PCIe 4.0 Graphics Port
/0/100/6/0       /dev/nvme0      storage        CT1000P3PSSD8
/0/100/6/0/0     hwmon1          disk           NVMe disk
/0/100/6/0/2     /dev/ng0n1      disk           NVMe disk
/0/100/6/0/1     /dev/nvme0n1    disk           1TB NVMe disk
/0/100/6/0/1/1   /dev/nvme0n1p1  volume         599MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/100/6/0/1/2   /dev/nvme0n1p2  volume         1GiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/6/0/1/3   /dev/nvme0n1p3  volume         929GiB EFI partition
/0/100/a                         generic        Raptor Lake Crashlog and Telemetry
/0/100/e                         storage        Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller Intel Corporation
/0/100/14                        bus            Raptor Lake USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 (20 Gb/s) XHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0      usb1            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/2                    input          AURA LED Controller
/0/100/14/0/6                    bus            ASM107x
/0/100/14/0/6/2  input3          input          Logitech G513 RGB MECHANICAL GAMING KEYBOARD Keyboard
/0/100/14/0/6/3  input10         input          Logitech USB Receiver Consumer Control
/0/100/14/0/e                    communication  AX211 Bluetooth
/0/100/14/1      usb2            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/1/9                    bus            ASM107x
/0/100/14.2                      memory         RAM memory
/0/100/14.3      wlp0s20f3       network        Raptor Lake-S PCH CNVi WiFi
/0/100/15                        bus            Raptor Lake Serial IO I2C Host Controller #0
/0/100/15.1                      bus            Raptor Lake Serial IO I2C Host Controller #1
/0/100/15.2                      bus            Raptor Lake Serial IO I2C Host Controller #2
/0/100/16                        communication  Raptor Lake CSME HECI #1
/0/100/17                        storage        Raptor Lake SATA AHCI Controller
/0/100/1a                        bridge         Raptor Lake PCI Express Root Port #25
/0/100/1b                        bridge         Raptor Lake PCI Express Root Port #17
/0/100/1b.4                      bridge         Raptor Lake PCI Express Root Port #21
/0/100/1b.4/0    /dev/nvme1      storage        CT1000P3PSSD8
/0/100/1b.4/0/0  hwmon2          disk           NVMe disk
/0/100/1b.4/0/2  /dev/ng1n1      disk           NVMe disk
/0/100/1b.4/0/1  /dev/nvme1n1    disk           1TB NVMe disk
/0/100/1c                        bridge         Raptor Lake PCI Express Root Port #1
/0/100/1c.2                      bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1c.2/0    eno1            network        Ethernet Controller I226-V
/0/100/1d                        bridge         Raptor Lake PCI Express Root Port #9
/0/100/1f                        bridge         Raptor Lake LPC/eSPI Controller
/0/100/1f/0                      system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/1                      communication  PnP device PNP0501
/0/100/1f/2                      system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/3                      system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/4                      system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/5                      system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/6                      system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f.3      card0           multimedia     Raptor Lake High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/1f.3/0    input18         input          HDA Intel PCH Front Mic
/0/100/1f.3/1    input19         input          HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic
/0/100/1f.3/2    input20         input          HDA Intel PCH Line
/0/100/1f.3/3    input21         input          HDA Intel PCH Line Out
/0/100/1f.3/4    input22         input          HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone
/0/100/1f.4                      bus            Raptor Lake-S PCH SMBus Controller
/0/100/1f.5                      bus            Raptor Lake SPI (flash) Controller
/1               input0          input          Sleep Button
/2               input1          input          Power Button
/3               input11         input          PC Speaker
/4               input12         input          Asus WMI hotkeys
/5               input13         input          Eee PC WMI hotkeys
/6               input2          input          Power Button

root@fedora:~# dnf list installed \*nvidia\*
Installed Packages
kmod-nvidia-latest-dkms.x86_64                                  3:550.54.15-1.fc39                                 @cuda-fedora39-x86_64
nvidia-driver.x86_64                                            3:550.54.15-1.fc39                                 @cuda-fedora39-x86_64
nvidia-driver-NVML.x86_64                                       3:550.54.15-1.fc39                                 @cuda-fedora39-x86_64
nvidia-driver-NvFBCOpenGL.x86_64                                3:550.54.15-1.fc39                                 @cuda-fedora39-x86_64
nvidia-driver-cuda.x86_64                                       3:550.54.15-1.fc39                                 @cuda-fedora39-x86_64
nvidia-driver-cuda-libs.x86_64                                  3:550.54.15-1.fc39                                 @cuda-fedora39-x86_64
nvidia-driver-devel.x86_64                                      3:550.54.15-1.fc39                                 @cuda-fedora39-x86_64
nvidia-driver-libs.x86_64                                       3:550.54.15-1.fc39                                 @cuda-fedora39-x86_64
nvidia-kmod-common.noarch                                       3:550.54.15-1.fc39                                 @cuda-fedora39-x86_64
nvidia-libXNVCtrl.x86_64                                        3:550.54.15-1.fc39                                 @cuda-fedora39-x86_64
nvidia-libXNVCtrl-devel.x86_64                                  3:550.54.15-1.fc39                                 @cuda-fedora39-x86_64
nvidia-modprobe.x86_64                                          3:550.54.15-1.fc39                                 @cuda-fedora39-x86_64
nvidia-persistenced.x86_64                                      3:550.54.15-1.fc39                                 @cuda-fedora39-x86_64
nvidia-settings.x86_64                                          3:550.54.15-1.fc39                                 @cuda-fedora39-x86_64
nvidia-xconfig.x86_64                                           3:550.54.15-1.fc39                                 @cuda-fedora39-x86_64



I found the problem. As I said in my question, this is a brand new pc.
Me being a noob, after building my first pc I went on youtube and looked for "First 10 things to do after building your pc". Guess what the youtuber suggested -> Enable XMP memory profile... All those crashes, freezes, etc, pointed to a RAM problem. Went into the BIOS, disabled it and I've been crash free for the last few hours. Feels amazing. Thanks everyone

I would do a memtest to see if a RMA case can be made for that RAM
